# Selenium specifying path to chromedriver.exe in Ruby capybara tests

Tags: ruby, selenium, rspec, capybara, selenium-chromedriver

We're using an Rspec - Capybara - Selenium stack to run acceptance tests.

I'd like to bundle chromedriver.exe with my app so I can control the version and use different versions between apps. Is this possible?

It seems like somewhere in my Capybara setup I should be able to specify this path, rather than relying on what's in the bin.

Comment: Do you want to switch path to **chromedriver.exe** inside the capybara tests?

Comment: Yes. I want to use a chromedriver.exe I have in my bin directory, rather than the one in the system bin, for all capybara tests.

Comment: Ok just try to fix the $PATH environment variable, to replace the **chromedriver.exe** placement, I believe it can be done before ruby Watir/Selenoum browser session. Do something like: `ENV[ 'PATH' ] = ('/custom/path:' << ENV[ 'PATH' ]).freeze`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.

Just add your `chromedriver.exe` binary to the project directory, then when you run your tests, be sure to use relative paths.

In Java, it would look something like this.

```
src/
  main/
    tests/
      MyTest.java
chromedriver.exe
```

Then the test would look like:

```
...
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver.exe");
...
```

In ruby, I assume it'd be something similar.

Also, if you intend to do something like this, i'd recommend stating the version in the executable. For example: `chromedriver-2.39.0.exe`